# CSS SVG Animation Steps

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I've just started fiddling with animating SVG's and I am trying to make a preloader. My problem is, that the animation is only doing half of what I want it to, and I really can't figure this one out!

I want it to go side to side like a metronome, not round like a clock!

Any help is appreciated!

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="198px" height="150px" viewBox="0 0 198 150" style="enable-background:new 0 0 198 150;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
<![CDATA[
 .st0{fill:url(#SVGID_1_);}
 .st1{fill:url(#SVGID_2_);}
 .st2{fill:url(#SVGID_3_);}
 .st3{fill:url(#SVGID_4_);}
 .st4{fill:#FF9E7F;}
]]>

.st0{
 opacity: 0.0;
 animation: pulse 1s infinite alternate;
}

.st1{
 opacity: 0.0;
 animation: pulse 1s infinite alternate;
 -webkit-animation-delay: -0.2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-delay: -0.2s;
}

.st4{
 opacity: 0.0;
 animation: pulse 1s infinite alternate;
 -webkit-animation-delay: -0.4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-delay: -0.4s;
}

.st3{
 opacity: 0.0;
 animation: pulse 1s infinite alternate;
 -webkit-animation-delay: -0.6s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-delay: -0.6s;
}


.st2{
 opacity: 0.0;
 animation: pulse 1s infinite alternate;
 -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-delay: -0.8s;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50%{
   opacity: 1;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

</style>
<g>
 <g>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="29.7813" y1="146.1855" x2="59.9984" y2="100.5993">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#75EBAF"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FFC57F"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <path class="st0" d="M49.5,135.994c27.338,0,49.5-19.557,49.5-19.557S76.839,96.883,49.5,96.883
   c-27.339,0-49.5,19.556-49.5,19.556S22.162,135.994,49.5,135.994z"/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="44.1196" y1="98.2666" x2="78.2921" y2="67.2485">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFC57F"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FF9E7F"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <path class="st1" d="M50.634,94.051c19.33,20,48.366,22.387,48.366,22.387s-2.306-30.042-21.637-50.042
   C58.032,46.394,28.997,44.007,28.997,44.007S31.302,74.049,50.634,94.051z"/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="179.1445" y1="144.6758" x2="103.2093" y2="74.7014">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#75EBAF"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#79C0E7"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <path class="st2" d="M148.5,96.881c-27.338,0-49.5,19.557-49.5,19.557s22.162,19.556,49.5,19.556s49.5-19.556,49.5-19.556
   S175.838,96.881,148.5,96.881z"/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_4_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="154.6924" y1="90.041" x2="108.9961" y2="68.3547">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#79C0E7"/>
   <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#FF9E7F"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <path class="st3" d="M120.637,66.394C101.307,86.396,99,116.438,99,116.438s29.035-2.387,48.366-22.387
   c19.331-20.001,21.638-50.044,21.638-50.044S139.968,46.394,120.637,66.394z"/>
  <path class="st4" d="M117.901,65.222c0,28.286-18.901,51.215-18.901,51.215s-18.901-22.93-18.901-51.215
   C80.099,36.936,99,14.006,99,14.006S117.901,36.936,117.901,65.222z"/>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```